# MediaWiki/Wikipedia URL sanitization regex

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, sanitization

When you create a page in MediaWiki/Wikipedia, the title is sanitized and used as part of the URL path. E.g. 'Lorem Ipsum' becomes 'Lorem_Ipsum'.

Do you known which *regex* is used for the sanitization? I can see it accepts also extended characters (like ü).

Comment: Why do you think it's a regex?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the settings of your wiki, but basically:

- Space is replaced with _ (they are treated as equal in the MediaWiki universe)
- Non ascii characters are escaped
- First character is made uppercase (this can be overridden)
- Forward slashes *can* be considered separators for page / subpage, depending on per namespace settings.

There are a few restrictions as well, e.g. titles cannot begin with a colon. See [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_title](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPage_title) for the full list.

Comment: Thanks for.the pointer, from there I got to the regex published here, https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgLegalTitleChars I am going to test it out.